# How to refer to a merged cell in a formula (or to a "bottom-up" range)

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I've got this (long) table on Google Sheets:

[image]

The cells of column B may be vertically merged, but the number of rows for each multi-cell is random.

Since, for each multi-cell, the top cell is the one containing the value, I need to use a formula which refers, for instance, to the cell `B1` in the cells `A1` and `A2`, to the cell `B3` in the cells `A3`, `A4` and `A5`, and so forth.

I thought to build a kind of bottom-up coalesce. E.g. if I'm in cell `A10`, I want to go from `$B10` towards the top until I find a non-null value (i.e. until `$B7`).
For doing this, I tried to insert the above formula in `A10`:

```
=INDEX($B10:$B$1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK($B10:$B$1),FALSE))
```

but it doesn't accept a range starting from a lower position with respect to the endpoint. Or, better, such range will be automatically flipped to `$B$1:$B10`. It follows that the first non-empty value is the one of `$B$1` and the returned value in `A10` is `3` instead of `1`.

Is there a way to express such inverted range? In case it isn't possible, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: just put those values from "B" in every row instead of merging to imply "the same in each row of this merge"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in A10 or any other row you can use:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(), IF(B:B<>"", {ROW(B:B), B:B}), 2))
```

[image]

if you want to fill the whole A column with B values use this in A1:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(B:B), IF(B:B<>"", {ROW(B:B), B:B}), 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can fill column C with values

```
=ArrayFormula(lookup(row(B1:B),row(B1:B)/if(B1:B<>"",1,0),B1:B))
```

or, for one specific row, you can retrieve the last value by

```
=ArrayFormula(lookup(row(),row(B$1:B)/if(B$1:B<>"",1,0),B$1:B))
```

[image]